How to append in already created service/bean (Dict<string, List<SomeInterface>) in IOC container in dot net?
I'm working on a .NET project and adding a Dictionary<string, > to the container. Using the statement below works fine.
However, I need to initially add a few classes to this dictionary and then add more later. I'm trying to use GetService<Dictionary<string, List>> to append additional classes, but it's not working. Please help me find the correct way to append more entries to it.
 builder.Services.AddScoped(sp =>
 {
     var options = sp.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<CommonOption>>().CurrentValue;
     var demoOptions = new Dictionary<string, List<SomeInterface>>();

     foreach (var kvp in options)
     {
         if(kvp.Key != "X")
         {
             continue;
         }
         var demoList = kvp.Value.Select(item => SomeMethod(item)).ToList();
         demoOptions .Add(kvp.Key, demoList);
     }
     return demoOptions;
 });

Now I want to append more classes in above dictinary where kvp.Key != "X". Above code in some other service so can't use if else.

This sounds like XY problem. What really are you trying to achieve with options containing interfaces? A factory of sorts?

Use singleton service as a sample.
Program.cs
builder.Services.Configure<CommonOption>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("CommonOption"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp =>
{
    var options = sp.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<CommonOption>>().CurrentValue.Options;
    var demoOptions = new Dictionary<string, List<TestInterface>>();

    foreach (var kvp in options)
    {
        if (kvp.Key == "X")
        {
            var demoList = kvp.Value.Select(item => TestMethodUtility.TestMethod(item)).ToList();
            demoOptions.Add(kvp.Key, demoList);
        }
    }
    return demoOptions;
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<DictionaryUpdateService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SomeOtherService>();

TestClass.cs
public class TestClass : TestInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "DefaultName";
}

TestInterface.cs
public interface TestInterface
{
    string Name { get; set; } 
}

TestMethod.cs
public static class TestMethodUtility
{
    public static TestInterface TestMethod(string input)
    {
        return new TestClass { Name = input };
    }
}

DistionaryUpdateService.cs
public class DictionaryUpdateService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<TestInterface>> _options;

    public DictionaryUpdateService(Dictionary<string, List<TestInterface>> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public void AppendEntries(IDictionary<string, List<TestInterface>> newEntries)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in newEntries)
        {
            if (_options.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
            {
                _options[kvp.Key].AddRange(kvp.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                _options[kvp.Key] = new List<TestInterface>(kvp.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}



